# background position for background color

Tags: css

Im able to give the start position of an background image. But if i give positions for solid fill background its not working.
Here is the js fiddle for that.

http://jsfiddle.net/yPVJE/

So can we set the start position and the size of an solid fill backgrounds?

Thanks!

Comment: i'm trying to get this effect http://jsfiddle.net/H48ua/, without the inner div ".bg" by transfering the ".bg" to the ".cover" div

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can not offset a background color. Only background images have a position.

Comment: hm, everything has a work-around

Answer (score 53):

I would take a similar approach to StuR, but using background position instead of gradient points. You can then set your background position as you would usually.

```
div {
  background:linear-gradient(left, #000, #000) no-repeat 50px 50px;
}
```

Comment: Note, this does not work with percentage values like 50%

Comment: Note, IE9 not & opera mini do not support linear-gradient

Comment: This appears more pixel-perfect. With just a linear-gradient I got some "blurry" lines in some browsers when the element was too big.

Comment: Some browsers are expecting new syntax `to left` instead of `left`. My Chrome (79) throws errors if the old syntax is used unless the `-webkit` prefix is used

Answer (score 22):

This is one way to offset a solid background color, using a linear gradient with a transparent colour for the first x number of pixels:

```
.offset {
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, transparent 300px,rgba(39,39,39,.5) 300px, rgba(39,39,39,.5) 100%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9ddZ/413/) on JSFiddle.

Comment: I went to the demo on JSFiddle and saw nothingness as a result, even if I push run. I was expecting the clr div background color just offset a bit, but nothing whatsoever showed. Is there an error in the script? For whatever it is worth, I tried adding the CSS from Ash's answer and saw nothingness too. I even tried adding that to the original one.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger - Try the JSFiddle link again, I've added browser prefixes to the CSS.

Comment: Thanks, the updated code worked. Note to others: The Visual Studio 2013 internal design view does not show the gradient/color. You must run the example in a real browser to see the result. I fell into this trap and tried to find out the difference between Fiddler and my browser (VS2013 Design View) and realized that VS is not a true browser and has limitations.

Comment: Voted for this because it allows the use of percentages not just pixel values.

Answer (score 10):

If you can make a ::before pseudo element with bg color, height and width and just offset it from its parent, you'll have complete control of its appearance. Much easier than putting a border in the pseudo element:

```
/* adding a ::before element with bg and border radius to create a
cropped circle to overlay parent bg image's blue right end */

.myElement::before {
  background-color: #fff;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 43px;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 201px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, using this you can offset a background-color indirectly.

Comment: I find this approach the best. If the `:before` pseudo element needs to be behind the content of `myElement`, make sure to specify `position:relevant` to `myElement`.

Answer (score 8):

Watch out for improper alignment when `linear-gradient` points are used.

Here's a better approach:

```
background: linear-gradient(#6699cc, #6699cc);
background-size: auto 4em;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

It uses `linear-gradient` **just** to  generate solid color, which is then resized to reflect the covered area size.

Also `background-position` could be used as needed, for example:

```css
background: linear-gradient(#6699cc, #6699cc);
background-size: calc(100% - 30px) auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;
```

In the last example, the background color would 'start' 30px from the left of the div.

Further reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: I chose this method for password strength on an input field. Onkeyup set style.backgroundSize = percentStrength + "% 100%"; The other approaches didn't seen to work for me.

Comment: Best approach in my opinion

Answer (score 7):

Yes, with linear-gradient it works:

```
div { background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 10px, grey 10px); }
```

Comment: `linear-gradient(to right, blue 10px, transparent 10px)` for horizontal

Answer (score 4):

You can use `background-size` instead of `background-position` to restrict the colored area:

```js
// randomly set background size every 1 second

var elm = document.querySelector('div');
window.setInterval(()=> {
  var randomValue = Math.random()*100;
  elm.style.backgroundSize = randomValue + '%';
}, 1000)
```

```css
div {
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   transition: .4s ease-out;
   
   background: linear-gradient(to right, black, black) no-repeat;
   background-size: 0;  /* <--- starting from 0% */
 }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I've been looking for this solution for ~2 hours! You sir/ma'am have made my day :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to accomplish this would be to add a pseudo-element to the div element like so:

```css
div {
  ::before {
    border-top: 10px solid #0066a4;
    content:"";
    margin: 0 auto; /* this centers the line to the full width specified */
    position: absolute; /* positioning must be absolute here, and relative positioning must be applied to the parent */
    top: 12px; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```

See this CodePen by Eric Rasch for a working example: https://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/Irlpm

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by having the parent element and child element `position: relative;`. Next, you can just go in and set offsets. There are a few other ways to achieve this but this is one of the many takes.

> SCSS:
> [image]

> HTML:
> [image]

> EXAMPLE:
> [image]

Note this might have side effects for buttons and links. Test it for your use case. Good luck!
*Happy Coding*